# Duplicate numbers in array | Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

For the life of me I can't figure out how to duplicate the numbers array.

Expected result: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Here is my code so far:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var result = numbers.map((number) => {
    return number
});

console.log(result);
```

I can't figure out how you can take the numbers array and then duplicate the array?

I was starting to do if statements - "If number is equal to 1 then return 1" but that would print the numbers like this `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]`

https://jsfiddle.net/e6jf74n7/1/

Comment: `var result = numbers.concat(numbers);`

Comment: How did you think would `map` work?

Comment: Iterate through each number and return them again at the end of the array

Comment: `map` is (more or less) `for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) r[i] = f(a[i]);` What you describe would be `for (i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i++) a.push(f(a[i]));`, which is not what `map` does.

Comment: Duplicate question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map will map all values one-to-one, that's why it's called "map"; it gives you one value, you return a value that should replace it.

To duplicate a list,  [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the list to itself:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var result = numbers.concat(numbers);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map won't work in this case just use concat

```
numbers.concat(numbers);
```

If you want to concat multiple times then

```
var concatArr = numbers;
 for (var i=0; i < 9 ; i++ ) {  
        numbers = numbers.concat(concatArr); 
   }
  console.log(numbers);
```

Concat docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 0):

fastest way is to use slice() then concat() to old array.

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
var clone = arr.slice(0);
var duplicate = arr.concat(clone);
```

Comment: It's even faster if you omit the `slice`…